# Plotting data lines from pandas dataframe, identified by keys in one column instead by different columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm running a simulation which gives me a csv file corresponding in structure to the following pandas data frame:

```
df = DataFrame({'series': {0: 'A',  1: 'B',  2: 'C',  3: 'A',  4: 'B',  5: 'C',  6: 'A',  7: 'B',  8: 'C',  9: 'A',  10: 'B',  11: 'C',  12: 'A',  13: 'B',  14: 'C'}, 'step': {0: '0',  1: '0',  2: '0',  3: '1',  4: '1',  5: '1',  6: '2',  7: '2',  8: '2',  9: '3',  10: '3',  11: '3',  12: '4',  13: '4',  14: '4'}, 'value': {0: '0',  1: '0',  2: '5',  3: '1',  4: '0',  5: '4',  6: '2',  7: '1',  8: '3',  9: '3',  10: '2',  11: '2',  12: '4',  13: '4',  14: '1'}})

    step  value series
0      0      0      A
1      0      0      B
2      0      5      C
3      1      1      A
4      1      0      B
5      1      4      C
6      2      2      A
7      2      1      B
8      2      3      C
9      3      3      A
10     3      2      B
11     3      2      C
12     4      4      A
13     4      4      B
14     4      1      C
```

**Given this `df`, how can I plot the `(step, value)` pairs for each series?**

That is, I would like to get the image

[image]

which would be easy to get (just `df2.plot("step")` if I could get my DataFrame into the format `df2`

```
   A  B  C  step
0  0  0  5     0
1  1  0  4     1
2  2  1  3     2
3  3  2  2     3
4  4  4  1     4
```

but I don't see how I would do the transformation `df`→`df2` or obtain the plot from `df` (which is what I get from my simulation) in any other way.

I could change my simulation code to write the corresponding data into in my case 16 separate table columns instead of one `series` and one `value` column, but that 16 is the value for most simulations, some use not all of those series and in the future I may need to split those further, so this does not look like the best solution to me.

---

To generate both example DataFrames, I went in the other direction and did

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({"step":xrange(5),"A":xrange(5),"B":[i*(i+1)/5 for i in xrange(5)],"C":xrange(5,0,-1)})
dfA = df2[["step","A"]].rename(columns={"A":"value"})
dfA["series"] = "A"
dfB = df2[["step","B"]].rename(columns={"B":"value"})
dfB["series"] ="B"
dfC = df2[["step","C"]].rename(columns={"C":"value"})
dfC["series"] ="C"
df = dfA.append(dfB).append(dfC).sort("step")
df.index = xrange(15)
```

Comment: It looks like you have trouble managing the csv file, and not plotting per se, is that right ? Supposing you named your csv as "a1.csv", does `d` in `d = {}; [d[item[0][0]].append(item[0][1]) if item[0][0] in d else d.update([
    (item[0][0], [item[0][1]])]) for item in [
        map(lambda x: (x[3], [int(x[1]), int(x[2])]), [line.split()])
        for line in open('a1.csv').readlines()[1:]]]; print d` contains what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to obtain the DataFrame in which you can plot more easily:

```
In [5]: df2 = DataFrame(dict(
                 (L, df[df['series'] == L]['value'].values)
                       for L in df['series'].unique()))

In [6]: df2
Out[6]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  5
1  1  0  4
2  2  1  3
3  3  2  2
4  4  4  1
```

If you set the index name to `'step'` you can plot as desired:

```
In [7]: df2.index.name = 'step'
Out[7]: 
      A  B  C
step         
0     0  0  5
1     1  0  4
2     2  1  3
3     3  2  2
4     4  4  1

In [8]: df2.plot()
```

*Which gives the desired figure.*